# How do I use the "Confident" card?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I found a "Twists of Fate" card in the "Special Delivery" chest at Gorhart - I assume for having played the demo.  I dismissed it pretty quickly, but I seem to remember it being titled "Confident."

However, "Confident" is not listed as one of the cards in the Destiny menu.  I also dug through my inventory and couldn't find it there.

How do I activate this card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indeed remembering the name correctly. Here it is:

[image]

Twists of Fate are permanent bonuses, so you don't need to activate it. You can view your Twists of Fate by going to Status -> Twists of Fate